# Is Docker ARG allowed within CMD instruction

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile where an `ARG` is used in the `CMD` instruction:

```
ARG MASTER_NAME
CMD spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master ${MASTER_URL}
```

The arg is passed via docker-compose:

```
  spark:
    build:
      context: spark
      args:
        - MASTER_URL=spark://master:7077
```

However, the `ARG` does not seem to get expanded for `CMD`. After I `docker-compose up`.

Here's what inspect shows:

```
docker inspect  -f "{{.Name}} {{.Config.Cmd}}" $(docker ps -a -q)
/spark {[/bin/sh -c spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master ${MASTER_URL}]}
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The thing is that `args` only can be used at build time, and the `CMD` is executing at run time. I guess that the only approach now to achieve what you want is setting an environment variable in the Dockerfile with the `MASTER_NAME` value.

```
ARG MASTER_NAME
ENV MASTER_NAME ${MASTER_NAME}
CMD spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master ${MASTER_NAME}
```

Comment: Why only environment variable is available at run time? Is the run-time process a child process of the building one?

Comment: Thanks, this solve my problem. But it still doesn't make sense for me, I assumed this should be evaluated in build process to full path anyway and saved in image as resolved variable (read argument).

Comment: Did you mean `ENV MASTER_URL ${MASTER_NAME}`?

Comment: thank you... lost so much time trying to debug whole configuration chain before reading this

Comment: @franklin-yu ENV variables are persisted inside the image. That's why are they available at run time.

Comment: This only worked for me when I added equals ("=") sign to it. 
E.g:

ARG IS_PROD=false
ENV IS_PROD=$IS_PROD

Comment: Thanks, @BobRoss, the same goes for me. I think the original answer should be updated with "=" sign.

Comment: This doesn't work at all in docker for windows. Neither ARG or ENV values can be expanded in RUN commands, none of any conceivable syntax works (%name%, $name, ${name}, etc.), and ENV values are not persisted in the image. They seem to have no effect at all. There's something seriously wrong with docker for windows.

Comment: In 2022 this works even on docker for windows. ENV and ARG names can be equal or different without problems. You don't need "=" sign in ENV definition. The answer is perfect as it is.

Comment: The curly brackets are not needed either