# Passing multiple classFile as argument to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM java:8
ARG cName
ADD target/jar1.jar p2p.jar
ADD ci/docker_entrypoint.sh .
CMD ["bash", "docker_entrypoint.sh" , "$cName"]
```

I have a docker_entrypoint.sh which look :

```
java -cp p2p.jar $1
```

I have multiple classes to run and I am providing className as input parameter to dockerfile. I am running couple of commands to build and run docker.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker-p2p --build-arg cName=com.HelloWorld .
docker run docker-p2p
```

after running the second command I am getting below error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class $cName
```

I am new to docker and I am not able to parameterise by dockerfile but when I mention a className "HelloWorld" in the dockerfile, it runs well. But when I try to pass parameters , it throws me out with this error.

Comment: did you try to remove the `"` quotes from `$cName` in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes I did. No Luck

Comment: You cannot use `ARG` in `CMD`. But there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560894/is-docker-arg-allowed-within-cmd-instrcution)

Comment: Additional check the diffrences between docker [run-cmd-entrypoint](http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/)

Comment: I am able to parameterise it now. Thanks . The Documentation helped me understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to differ between docker **run**, **cmd** and **entrypoint**.

For your example you can use an entrypoint and set the parameter via an environment variable.

One simple and easy Dockerfile example could be:

```
FROM java:8
ENV NAME="John Dow"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo Hello, $NAME"]
```

with `docker build . -t test` and `docker run -e NAME="test123" test`

Also have a look at some further docu: [docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint](http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/).

Answer (score 1):

If you do wind up with a Docker image that can do multiple things, it's a little unusual to create one image per task the way you're describing.  You can pass additional command-line parameters in `docker run` or most other ways to start a container, and you can use that to control what the image does.

For example, you might want to set up your image so that you can run

```sh
docker run ... docker-p2p com.HelloWorld
```

passing the class name as an argument.  I'd write an entrypoint script that wrapped this in a `java` call if appropriate (but passed through non-class names, like `docker run ... sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
case "$1" of
  com.*) exec java "$@" ;;
  *) exec "$@" ;;
esac
```

The corresponding Dockerfile doesn't take any ARGs; it could be

```sh
FROM java:8

# I prefer COPY to ADD, unless you explicitly want automatic
# HTTP fetches and/or tar file extraction.
COPY target/jar1.jar /p2p.jar
COPY ci/docker_entrypoint.sh /

# Globally set the class path.  (A Docker image only does one thing.)
ENV CLASSPATH /p2p.jar

# Always launch the entrypoint script.
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker_entrypoint.sh"]

# Give a default command, which with our script is a class name.
CMD ["com.HelloWorld"]
```

If you actually want a container per task, you could create a base image that contained everything up to the `ENTRYPOINT` line, and then created derived images `FROM` that base image that just set a different `CMD`.