# Docker-compose args are not passed to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file, and in that a build context for a given service with a `Dockerfile`.

Sample docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:

  scd-service:
    build:
      context: ./cmd/some-service/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        broker: redis:6379
        queue: somequeue
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - backend

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend
```

It can find the `Dockerfile` and build it with: `docker-compose up --build some-service`

However, this will fail. The `broker` and `queue` args are never passed to the given Dockerfile.

Sample `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.11

// stuff...

ARG broker
ARG queue

CMD ["go", "run", "/go/src/github.com/org/project/cmd/some-service/some-service.go", "--broker $broker", "--queue $queue"]
```

As evident in the build stage, these are never parsed:

```
Step 7/7 : CMD ["go", "run", "/go/src/github.com/org/project/cmd/some-service/some-service.go", "--broker $broker", "--queue $queue"]
```

Whereafter the Go program crashes as the command line parameters are invalid.

How does one parse args from `docker-compose` to a `Dockerfile`?

Edit: Weirdly, I can echo the correct value?

Example:

```
ARG broker
ARG queue

RUN echo ${broker}
```

Outputs:

```
Step 7/8 : RUN echo ${broker}
 ---> Running in c84828847d9a
redis:6379
```

How is this not parsed onto the CMD?

Comment: Build-args are only available at build-time, but `CMD` entry executes at run-time. Here's a reference and a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560894/is-docker-arg-allowed-within-cmd-instruction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems here. `ARG` is only used at build time, when creating the image, and `CMD` defines a step at run time, when running your container. `ARG` gets implemented as an environment variable for `RUN` steps, so it is up to the shell to expand the environment variable. And the json syntax doesn't run a shell. So to do this with `CMD`, you need to make two changes.

First, you need to save your `ARG` as an `ENV` value that gets saved to the image metadata and used to setup the environment when creating the container.

And second, you need to switch from an exec/json syntax for running `CMD` to run a shell that will expand these variables. Docker does this for you with the string syntax.

The end result looks like:

```
FROM golang:1.11

// stuff...

ARG broker
ENV broker=${broker}
ARG queue
ENV queue=${queue}

CMD go run /go/src/github.com/org/project/cmd/some-service/some-service.go --broker "$broker" --queue "$queue"
```

---

As an aside, you should also note that every argument in exec syntax needs to be a separate array entry, e.g.:

```
CMD ["go", "run", "/go/src/github.com/org/project/cmd/some-service/some-service.go", "--broker $broker", "--queue $queue"]
```

is similar to running:

```
go run /go/src/github.com/org/project/cmd/some-service/some-service.go "--broker $broker" "--queue $queue"
```

when you really wanted to run:

```
CMD ["go", "run", "/go/src/github.com/org/project/cmd/some-service/some-service.go", "--broker", "your_broker", "--queue", "your_queue"]
```

which would be similar to:

```
go run /go/src/github.com/org/project/cmd/some-service/some-service.go --broker "your_broker" --queue "your_queue"
```

(Note I removed the variables from my example because they do not work in the exec syntax.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems like the container cannot see the redis container otherwise specified now, but one problem at a time. Cheers, it worked.

Comment: ARG can be used during BUILD time as well as during RUN time but it needs to be declared as mentioned in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Comment: @AshishSingh the RUN step is performed at build time, when you create the image. The CMD step is executed at runtime, when you create the container. Yes the terminology is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You should set them as `ENV`, if you want them to be avaliable on containers based on the image (running-side). Something like:

```
ENV broker $broker   //assign your env broker value to container
ENV queue  $queue
```

**ARG**

These are avaliable when you create the image, but not when you want to run a container based on that.

**ENV**

`ENV` values are available to containers and also RUN-style commands. If you want the **arguments to be avaliable during runtime**, these are the good ones.

You also may find useful info about env values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers).

Edit. In order to avoid *[Warning] One or more build-args [] were not consumed* message, you should do something like:

```
ARG broker=your.broker.value
ENV broker=${broker}
```

The error is telling that you have unused ARGS (altough you may be ok without setting them now that you have ENVs). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651369/docker-one-or-more-build-args-where-not-consumed) as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Just swapping out `ARG` with `ENV` appears to be invalid syntax.

Comment: sure! it's a silly example, but the provided link may guide you better : )

Comment: With your example, I get: `[Warning] One or more build-args [queue broker] were not consumed`

Comment: Edited, that seems to be related to not-using the args you provide (*silly docker*)

Comment: What is `your.broker.value` referring to? This is what should be passed on from docker-compose, presumably?