# Spring boot cant find application-$profile.properties file: Docker file

Tags: spring-boot, dockerfile

Docker file: Spring unable to find profile.properties file

FROM java:8u111-jre

```
ARG VERSION
ARG PROFILE

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chown 1001:0 -R /app
RUN chmod 777 /app
COPY target/jira2bd-$VERSION.jar app.jar
USER 1001

CMD java  $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar --spring.profiles.active=$PROFILE
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: Please provide the docker command you use to build the image. Did you pass some values for VERSION and PROFILE arguments?

Answer (score 0):

How I know Docker ARGs are not allowed in CMD instruction.

The solution is to convert them into the ENV variables. Try something like that

```
ARG PROFILE
ENV PROFILE ${PROFILE}

CMD java  ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app.jar --spring.profiles.active=${PROFILE}
```

Also take a look here [Is Docker ARG allowed within CMD instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560894/is-docker-arg-allowed-within-cmd-instruction)