# Unable to solve this basic error invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I am  trying to automate the process of building a docker image . I have the following docker image passing a command line argument, retrieving the argument in python script.

Automate

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t test . --build-arg split=$split
docker run --rm -it test
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latst-py3
RUN mkdir -p /test/src
ARG split
WORKdir  /test/src
COPY . ./
CMD["python", "script.py","$split"]
```

python script

```
m1=testing(int(sys.argv[1])
```

Running bash script

```
bash ./automate.sh 5
```

while running the above code I am retrieving the below error

```
ValueErro: invalid literal for int() with base 10; 'split'
```

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question [Is Docker ARG allowed within CMD instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560894/is-docker-arg-allowed-within-cmd-instruction)? I'm relatively noob when it comes to Docker but quite obviously you're passing the string "split" to Python, instead of the numeral string from command line, so apparently the `$split` doesn't resolve to the actual argument value, and according to the link that is actually expected with `CMD`.

Comment: It appears that `$split` is not being expanded as you expected.

Comment: In your Python script why don’t you simply print `sys.argv`?

Comment: @barny no need, the error message already tells you what it is: `'split'`.

Comment: Yes, but if OP learns to debug even if only by printing what is causing the error, perhaps they’ll get better at debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$split is empty inside the automate.sh file.

If you want to pass value 5 as inside automate.sh, it is available as the first arg of the bash script, so you can get it’s value as $1

In summary, if you execute:

```
bash ./automate.sh 5
```

then $0 is ./automate.sh inside the script and $1 is 5. This is called positional arguments. If you do in fact want to get the value from $split then do this:

```
split=5 bash ./automate.sh
```

That would solve the error.
However seeing your Docker recipe, there is a better way to do this.

Your Docker ARG split argument is in fact not used at build time at all. It was only referenced in CMD, which is why it would be empty. To refer it inside the shell at runtime (not build time) you need ENV instead. Specifying ENV value is not possible from build time, but rather at runtime using docker run command. You can only specify it’s default value in the Dockerfile.

Lastly, since you only use split in the CMD, it’s possible to not use ENV at all and just specify it as the command parameter in docker run positional arguments. It would be something like:

```
docker run myimage python script.py 5
```

Comment: Also worth noting that, using the JSON-array form `CMD [..., "$split"]`, nothing processes those command words at all: the script is being passed the literal string `$split` as a parameter.

Comment: Nice comment! Hence the error.
The whole script + Dockerfile recipe seems like a quiz for me that tests your understanding about how bash process arguments, and the difference between build ARG and docker ENV.
I wanted to just provides this in the original comment, not as answer, but my current reputation does not allow me.

Comment: Thank you so much @lucernae, now it's working perfectly fine. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Glad that it helps